# "message":"No living connections","node_env":"production"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'am trying to install Kibana 4 in my machine but it's giving the following errors.

```
{"@timestamp":"2015-04-15T06:25:50.688Z","level":"error","node_env":"production","error":"Request error, retrying -- connect ECONNREFUSED"}
{"@timestamp":"2015-04-15T06:25:50.693Z","level":"warn","message":"Unable to revive connection: http://0.0.0.0:9200/","node_env":"production"}
{"@timestamp":"2015-04-15T06:25:50.693Z","level":"warn","message":"No living connections","node_env":"production"}
{"@timestamp":"2015-04-15T06:25:50.698Z","level":"fatal","message":"No Living connections","node_env":"production","error":{"message":"No Living connections","name":"Error","stack":"Error: No Living connections\n  at sendReqWithConnection (/home/kibana-4.0.0-rc1-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:174:15)\n
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ECONNREFUSED` is telling you that it can't connect to Elasticsearch.  The `http://0.0.0.0:9200/` tells you what it's trying to connect to.

You need to modify the `config/kibana.yml` and change the `elasticsearch_url` setting to point to your cluster.  If you are running Elasticsearch on the same box, the correct value is `http://localhost:9200`.

Answer (score 0):

Your elastic search is down. 
In my case it was because the environment variable `Java_Home` was not set
 correctly.You have to manually set it. These are the guides lines to do it :

1. Go to your PC Environments.
2. Create a new variable,with variable name `Java_Home`. The variable value should be java installation path.
3. Make sure your path has no spaces. If your Java is in Program Files(x86) you can use shortcut which is : `progra~2` instead of `Program Files(x86)`.

As a result you have something like this : `C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.8.0_131`

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason why this might happen in the case you are using AWS Elasticsearch service.

No grant right access policies for ES and not loading right AWS credential will be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more posibility, maybe your elasticsearch does not run properly as you want: please check [this link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25067#issuecomment-482270190) and try to dockerize the elasticsearch.

for me this docker-compose.yml file can dockerize the elasticsearch:

```yaml
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: "${CREATED_IMAGE_NAME_PREFIX}:1"
    container_name: efk_elastic
    build:
      context: ./elasticsearch
      args:
        EFK_VERSION: $EFK_VERSION
        ELASTIC_PORT1: $ELASTIC_PORT1
        ELASTIC_PORT2: $ELASTIC_PORT2
    environment:
      # node.name: node
      # cluster.name: elasticsearch-default
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms1g -Xmx1g
      discovery.type: single-node
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      http.cors.enabled: "true"
      http.cors.allow-credentials: "true"
      http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
      http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
    hostname: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "${ELASTIC_EXPOSED_PORT1}:$ELASTIC_PORT1"
      - "$ELASTIC_EXPOSED_PORT2:${ELASTIC_PORT2}"
    volumes:
      # - type: bind
      #   source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      #   target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      #   read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch_data
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - efk
```

please note that this is not complete. for more details please see my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nodejsdeveloperskh/docker/tree/docker-compose/docker-compose-files/EFK-filebeat)