# Configuring ELK with Kitematic - Elastic Search won't start - localhost not available

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, kibana, elastic-stack, kitematic

I am trying to set up ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) with Kitematic. I have followed these interactions [here](https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io). Steps taken:

1. Installed Kitematic
2. Downloaded the ELK package
3. Run the container
4. I am given the following ports:

[image]

I can access Kibana on http://192.168.99.100:32839/app/kibana, but see this error:

[image]

http://localhost:9200 returns a server not found error.

[image]

I then ssh into the container and try to run `service start elasticsearch` but receive the following failure:

`* Starting Elasticsearch Server                                                                sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Read-only file system                                                                [fail]`

My question(s):

1. Am I wrong to expect to be able to reach the containers services via http://localhost:
2. Why does elastic search not start?
3. Can I connect the output of my own script (twitter sentiment analysis data) to elastic search by specifying the elastic search container url?

My own investigations:

1. [article3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-common-elk-stack-issues)
2. [article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643060/messageno-living-connections-node-envproduction)
3. [article2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145382/cannot-start-kibana-4-1-2)

New to Docker, so apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: What is your docker version, and your OS?

Comment: `docker --version
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e` and `mac os x`

Comment: With docker machine on Mac? Or with the new xhyve docker for Mac?

Comment: Originally I tried boot2docker, but now using the Docker Toolbox (https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox)

Comment: So maybe a port-forwarding issue then

Comment: could this be a conflict due to boot2dock and docker toolbox?

Comment: It should not, but I don't know xhyve well enough.

Comment: Can you run the ELK one by one. Just use the official images on Docker hub and then linking them . I could not start the ELK from sebp/elk.